# Infinite-dimensional translation-invariant measure

Tags: measure-theory

Why is there no translation-invariant measure on an infinite-dimensional Euclidean space? Is there a reasonably short, insightful proof?

I am interested in an infinite-dimensional space with a definite inner product but not necessarily complete in the corresponding topology. Thus it need not be a Hilbert space.

Comment: See also problem 18 in Halmos's [Hilbert space problem book](http://books.google.com/books?id=S57XLkgbf0oC&pg=PA10)

Comment: Is the asserted duplicate really a duplicate? It is about Hilbert space, whereas this one might be on $\mathbb R^\omega$ (i.e. the space of functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ with _finite_ support). The answer to the existing question depends on the space being Banach, which $\mathbb R^\omega$ isn't.

Comment: @Henning: I think so. Nate's answer works just as well in any Hausdorff (separable) topological vector space as he points out in an exercise immediately following theorem 1.1 in his notes.

Comment: @t.b.: Okay -- but the theorem _as quoted in the answer_ did include an explicit requirement that it was a Banach space. I see that the question is tagged (hilbert-spaces), but that tag didn't come from the OP.

Comment: I am interested in an infinite-dimensional space with a definite inner product but not necessarily closed in the corresponding topology. Thus it need not be a Hilbert space.

Comment: And the same proof works.  Any ball of your inner-product space contains infinitely many disjoint balls of the same (smaller) radius which are all translates of each other.

Comment: Some remarks: [this MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61610/measures-on-infinite-dimensional-banach-spaces/65982#65982) gives some answers in the non-Borel and non-separable cases. And stealing a link from Michael Greinecker from MO, [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1992-27-02/S0273-0979-1992-00328-2/S0273-0979-1992-00328-2.pdf) gives several references to the statement that "any $\sigma$-finite quasiinvariant Borel measure on a infinite dim LCTVS must be zero".

Comment: @Henning: ah, I hadn't noticed that the hilbert-space tag didn't come from the op.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The statement in the question "Why is there no translation-invariant measure on an infinite-dimensional Euclidean space?" is not correct.

(i) **A counting measure defined in infinite-dimensional Euclidean space is  an example of such measure which  is translation-invariant.**

(ii)**There does not exist a translation-invariant Borel measure  in an infinite-dimensional Euclidean space $\ell_2$ which gets the value 1 on the unit ball.**  Indeed, assume the contrary  and let $\mu$ be such a measure. let $(e_k)_{k \in N}$ be a standard basis with $||e_k||=1$ for $k \in N$. Let $B_k$ be an open ball with center at $\frac{e_k}{2}$ and with radius $r$ less than $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. Then $(B_k)_{k \in N}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint open balls with radius $r$. On the one hand, $\mu$ measure of $B_k$ must be zero because in other case the $\mu$ measure of the unit ball will be $+\infty$. On the other hand, since $\ell_2$ is separable, $\ell_2$ can be covered by countably many translations of $B_1$ which together with an invariance of $\mu$ implies that $\mu$ measure of $\ell_2$ is zero. This is a contradiction and assertion (ii) is proved.

(iii) **There exists  a translation-invariant measure  on an infinite-dimensional Euclidean space $\ell_2$ which gets the value 1 on the parallelepiped $P$ defined by $P=\{x : x \in \ell_2 ~\&~ |<x,e_k>|\le \frac{1}{2^k}\}$.**

Let $\lambda$ be infinite-dimensional  Lebesgue measure in $R^{\infty}$ (see, [Baker R., ``Lebesgue measure" on~$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$,*Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.*, vol. 113, no. 4, 1991,
pp.1023--1029](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-09/S0002-9939-04-07372-1/)).  We set

$$
(\forall X)(X \in {\cal{B}}(\ell_2) \rightarrow \mu(X)=\lambda(T(X)))
$$ 
where ${\cal{B}}(\ell_2)$  denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of  Borel subsets of $\ell_2$

and the mapping  $T : \ell_2 \to R^{\infty} $ is defined by: $T(\sum_{k \in N}a_ke_k)=(2^{k-1}a_k)_{k \in N}$.

Then  $\mu$ satisfies all conditions participated in (iii).

P.S. There exist many interesting translation-invariant non-sigma finite Borel measures in infinite-dimensional separable Banach spaces(see, for example,  [G.Pantsulaia , On generators of shy sets on  Polish topological vector spaces, New  York   J.  Math.,14 ( 2008) ,  235 – 261](http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2008/14-11.html))